# "... nor X either" and "... or X either"

Tags: word-usage, syntactic-analysis

My question is: are the following sentences acceptable in English?

> "I have never had a car, nor a bicycle either"
>
> "I have never had a car, or a bicycle either"

I am not asking what the best structure is (probably "I have never had a car, nor a bicycle" or "I have never had a car, or a bicycle"): just if the two structures above are acceptable. My understanding is that the structure "... nor X either" would add strength to the sentence (at least in a conversation if not on a written document).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of them sound okay to me. :)

.

For your first example:

> - 1.) "I have never had a car, nor a bicycle either."

Grammatically, that seems fine. In the 2002 reference grammar by Huddleston and Pullum et al., *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (CGEL), page 1309, there's a section on "*Nor* as coordinator", and below is a relevant excerpt from it  (note the three examples in **[50.ii]**) :

> *Nor* as coordinator
>
> *Nor* appears as a coordinator paired correlatively with *neither* ([50.i]), or non-correlatively as a variant of *or* in negative contexts ([50.ii]):
>
> [50]
>
> - i.a. *[Neither Jill nor her husband] could help us.*
> - i.b. *A good conversationalist talks [neither too much nor too little].*
>
>     -
> - ii.a. *The change won't be [as abrupt as in 1958 nor as severe as in 1959].*
> - ii.b. *No state shall have a share [less than 50% nor more than 70%].*
> - ii.c. *Serious art is not [for the lazy, nor for the untrained].*
>
> In [ii] *nor* could be replaced by (*or*, which is much more common:
>   the version with *nor* perhaps gives added emphasis to the negation. .
>   . . The difference is that in [i] all the coordinates are marked as
>   negative, whereas in the non-correlative [ii] the first coordinate
>   (*as abrupt as in 1958*, etc.) is not marked as negative within the
>   coordination itself, but falls within the scope of a preceding
>   negative.

.

For your second example:

> - 2.) "I have never had a car, or a bicycle either."

Grammatically, that seems fine. Your "either" seems to be functioning as a connective adjunct. Here are some examples that might be somewhat similar in some ways:

- *She wasn't impressed, (and) I wasn't either.* -- (CGEL, page 1308)
- *Kim didn't go and Pat didn't, either.* -- (CGEL, page 1305, fn 25)
- *Kim didn't like it either.* -- (CGEL, page 570)

.

So, it seems to me that both examples are fine.

Comment: So apparently I could say "She wasn't impressed, nor I was either"?

Comment: @randomatlabuser: "she wasn't impressed and neither was I" would be much more idiomatic

Comment: @No'am Newman: I agree that it would be more idiomatic, more common. But I am trying to understand if the structure "nor X either" is acceptable, perhaps producing a different emphasis, a different sound and being pronounced with a different cadence: "neither was I" sounds quick and the accent falls on "I" at the end, while "nor I was either" sounds slower, almost pedantic, and the accent falls on "I" at the second syllable (it also seems more amusing).

Comment: @randomatlabuser: The suggestion by *No'am Newman* sounds good. You could also perhaps try "*She wasn't impressed, nor was I (either?).*" The "either" in this last example probably isn't fully acceptable, or it might be acceptable in some dialects, or it might be colloquial usage, but I'm not sure on this; but the version without "either" seems to be fine, imo. Notice that in both my version and in *No'am Newman's* version the occurrence of obligatory subject-auxilary inversion in the 2nd coordinate ("and neither was I"; "*nor was I*").

Answer (score 2):

"Nor" is a contraction of Middle English "nauther", becoming "neither" in modern English. "Nor" is often paired with "neither". Since "never" (in the first sentence) carries the sense of negation, in a similar way that "neither" does, I believe the first sentence is acceptable, while the second might be a little unwelcoming in written usage.

Answer (score 0):

***Neither*** and ***nor*** always go together. You can’t use ***nor*** in a sentence without ***neither***.

***Either*** and ***nor*** never go together. If you use ***either*** you have to use ***or***.

***Either*** can be used at the end of a sentence without ***or***—“He didn’t do his homework either.”

"I have never had a car, nor a bicycle either" is incorrect because you’re pairing ***nor*** with ***either***.

In the second sentence, drop the comma before ***or,*** and drop the ***either***.

“I have never had a car or a bicycle” says it all.